# How can I get my javascript gererated data from the client to the server via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, data-transfer

A while back I wrote a rather long javascript procedure for organizing data we receive at work.  The user simply paste in the mess we get and script throws out all the worthless info and generates a nice cleaned up data table.

I would like to add the ability to then transfer the processed information to the mySQL database.  I'm growing a bit more comfortable using javascript, but I don't have close to the time or know-how to recreate the long processing procedure in PHP.  How should I prep the data in javascript to most efficiently hand off the data to the server and have PHP insert it into mySQL tables?

The less PHP server side the better, although I doubt it would be safe to have a PHP page that blindly followed any instructions a referring page might send it.

At this point the data my script presents in the browser looks a lot like mySQL records already.

ex.

```
(Wilson, Paul, 1000400, A399)
(Smalls, Kalah, 4993944, B11)
(Chase, Danny, 244422, B133)
(Larson, Jay, 3948489, J39)
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you could have the data in a JSON array.

Then on the php side use json_decode to pull the data in as an array loop through it and do your updates and inserts for your data in MySQL.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php